# ODOO ECO after rejected ，BOM or Product cannot recovery initial version

Tags: odoo, eco

I changed BOM in ECO. But when user rejected， it did not rollback?
Bug or my operation is short of step.
Can give me some advice. apply change and apply rebase did not work

Comment: Hi zhang john, welcome to stackoverflow. can you be more specify on your question please?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.